# Get order Collection of last 14 days based on product collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I have already product collection which fetches product based on category id, now I want to fetch only products which are ordered from last 14 days from above condition

Any SOlution?

```
public function getProductCollectionByCategories()
    {
        $ids = $this->cat_id;
        $to = date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); // current date
        $from = strtotime('-15 day', strtotime($to));
        $from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $from); // 2 days before

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $ids]);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', '0');
        $collection->setPageSize(2);
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: You will have to start collection logic from "sales_order_item" table. Get the list of products ordered in last 14 days by adding date filter on "created_at" date in item table. Then you need to join it with product collection to get selected product data.

Comment: @PratikNavapara any samples or help will be beneficial I am new to Magento

Comment: you will get order collection of before 14 days and in this collection you will get products